# dart web : couldn't run webdev

Tags: dart-pub, dart-html

I installed webdev to run dart web but when I want to run webdev it's showing an error:

```
Building package executable... 
Failed to build webdev:webdev:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dds-2.1.6/lib/src/cpu_samples_manager.dart:54:21: Error: Type 'CpuSamplesEvent' not found.
  void cacheSamples(CpuSamplesEvent samples) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dds-2.1.6/lib/src/cpu_samples_manager.dart:54:21: Error: 'CpuSamplesEvent' isn't a type.
  void cacheSamples(CpuSamplesEvent samples) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just fixed that.

I edited `cpu_samples_manager.dart` in `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dds-2.1.6/lib/src/` and replace `CpuSamplesEvent` with `var`. ;)

anyway, if there is a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs with 2.14.1 of dart, and maybe previous versions. You can update to 2.15.1 of Dart and this will disappear.

There is an official fix in DDS 2.1.6+1 which also fixes the issue, but webdev loads 2.1.6.

You can make it use the new version by calling `pub global activate webdev` then after you have received the error call `pub global activate dds 2.1.6+1` then re-run `pub global activate webdev` which will succeed.

I put issue on their SDK github, hopefully this will be resolved soon.

Comment: now it's working, thank you.

Comment: "You can update to 2.15.1 of Dart and this will disappear." This does not seem to be the case. I still get the same error with 2.15.1. Also, the fix does not work when webdev actually runs.

Comment: This has been patched now by dart, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47978
If you still have issues deactivate webdev, then run `dart pub cache clean` and then reactivate webdev, it should pull that patched version.